# File upload in Oracle apex for virus scanning

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle19c, oracle-apex21.2

I'm working on app where user will upload files. These files need to be scanned for malware and then stored in Azure storage (will be done by REST APIs). I don't want to upload files to actual database at any instance hence APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES or other BLOB approach can't be used as these will store file in database even it might be temporary or session based.

If apex file browse item is used, on page submit it automatically uploads the file to APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES which I don't want. Is there a way I can use apex file browse but not upload to APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES?

Or if anyone have used malware scanning with Apex?

Comment: APEX itself does not interact with file system or other external storage. The only thing it can see directly is the database. Generally speaking you would need to store the file in the database first, and then make REST calls from stored procedures to copy the BLOB data into the cloud storage. If you wanted do bypass the database, you'd probably have to code your own Javascript plugin or something similar to do the job.

Comment: @pmdba yes I'm writing custom code for JS but at the end when I submit page for other page items, the file item is also submitted along with them, trying to avoid that.

Comment: ORDS has a setting to configure an ICAP server for virus scanning. I have not worked with this myself but that is where I would start. Virus scanning should be transparent, I wouldn't build my own solution as it seems you're doing

Comment: Yes @KoenLostrie ICAP would be ideal but the organization I work for is not going to use ICAP because of their own reasons